# Is there an equivalent of analytic meditation in Protestantism?

Tags: protestantism, meditation

Analytic meditation, [as defined](http://dharmakaya.org/practices/analytic-meditation/):

> Our minds are filled with confused thoughts and beliefs; often, even when we recognize logically that our beliefs are wrong, they are so embedded that they are virtually impossible to shed. By employing vigorous analytical methods and reasoning, we can deconstruct these beliefs, actively examining the concepts we cling to and questioning whether they really exist. With practice, logic becomes more sustainable, and understanding gains force, leading to wisdom.

Is there any equivalent of analytic meditation in any Christian tradition/denomination/sect, specifically in ***Protestant*** tradition? If yes, what are the supporting scriptures?

Comment: As an engineer, I'm curious to know what point of reference analytic meditation would use to judge whether or not a belief is wrong?  Each Christian denomination will present itself as correct, and analytical reasoning is occasionally incompatible with faith (such as believing in the resurrection of Christ, for which the average person will throughout their lives have no empirical proof and must rely on spiritual feelings of the heart).

Comment: @JBH, that's a good question. You would like to start another one?

Comment: It would be an inappropriate question for here as I suspect the question has nothing to do with Christianity.  That's why I asked you.  I apologize that I don't have the time to review the entire Dharmakaya website, but what does the philosophy suggest is the point of reference?

Comment: Faith cometh by hearing. Romans 10:17. And hearing by the word of God. The word is spoken and faith receives the word.